# get child from parent/child array list

Tags: php

I have a serious issues about how to get some field from a parent/child array list

my list :

```
Array
(
[356] => Array
    (
        [label] => Monde entier
        [childrens] => Array
            (
                [355] => Array
                    (
                        [label] => International (hors U.E)
                        [childrens] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [354] => Array
                    (
                        [label] => Europe
                        [childrens] => Array
                            (
                                [353] => Array
                                    (
                                        [label] => France entière
                                        [childrens] => Array
                                            (
                                                [146] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [label] => Nord
                                                        [childrens] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [161] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [label] => Champagne-Ardenne
                                                                        [childrens] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [258] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [label] => Ardennes
                                                                                        [childrens] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                                [260] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [label] => Aube
                                                                                        [childrens] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                                [302] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [label] => Marne
                                                                                        [childrens] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                                [303] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [label] => Haute-Marne
                                                                                        [childrens] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [169] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [label] => Nord-Pas-de-Calais
                                                                        [childrens] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [310] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [label] => Nord
                                                                                        [childrens] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                                [313] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [label] => Pas-de-Calais
                                                                                        [childrens] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                                [173] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [label] => Picardie
                                                                        [childrens] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [252] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [label] => Aisne
                                                                                        [childrens] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                                [311] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [label] => Oise
                                                                                        [childrens] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                                [331] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [label] => Somme
                                                                                        [childrens] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                              ......

                                                [152] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [label] => Dom-Tom
                                                        [childrens] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [178] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [label] => Dom-Tom
                                                                        [childrens] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                                [347] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [label] => Guadeloupe
                                                                                        [childrens] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                                [348] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [label] => Martinique
                                                                                        [childrens] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                                [349] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [label] => Guyane
                                                                                        [childrens] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                                [350] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [label] => Réunion
                                                                                        [childrens] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                                [352] => Array
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        [label] => Autres DOM-TOM 
                                                                                        [childrens] => Array
                                                                                            (
                                                                                            )

                                                                                    )

                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

So i want to create a function to return me an array with list like that :

[image]

and my function :

```
public function getListArray(array $config['place']) {



.....

return $result;

}
```

Comment: I have really no idea to do it with recursivity function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
function getListArray($array) {
  static $level = -1;
  static $result = array();
  $level++;
  foreach ($array as $arr) {
    $result[] = str_repeat ('-', $level).$arr['label'];
    if (is_array($arr['childrens'])) {
      getListArray($arr['childrens']);
    }
  }
  $level--;

  return $result;
}
```

Comment: really I would to thank you you saved my life,you are not on gmail maybe?

Comment: I have now another problem,how to remove label "Monde Entier" with index "356" from the list and put "International (hors U.E)" with Index 355 in the end of list?

Comment: try this `foreach ($result as $key =>$value) {if (false!==stripos($value, 'Monde Entier')) { unset($result[$key]); }}`

Comment: `$result[] = 'International (hors U.E)';`

Comment: Now I have another issues,I hope to access to any childrens of list with Id (parenId) because I want use my form in a lot of otgher forms according with region so in the other word a part of list in relationship with region Id?

Comment: `function getRegionMembers($array, $id) {
  static $level = 0;
  static $is_in_region = false;
  static $result = array();
  if ($is_in_region){
    $level++;
  }
  foreach ($array as $key =>$arr) {
    if (!$is_in_region && $id == $key) { 
      $is_in_region = true;
    }
    if ($is_in_region){
      $result[$key] = str_repeat ('-', $level).$arr['label'];
    }
    if (is_array($arr['childrens'])){
      getRegionMembers($arr['childrens'], $id);
    }
    if ($is_in_region && $id == $key){ 
      $is_in_region = false;
    }
  }
  if ($is_in_region){
    $level--;
  }
  return $result;
}`

Comment: it's works like a charm...I dont know how much I will thank you...

Comment: we can chat on gmail im on line just accept my invitation...

Comment: @air4x: http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/

Comment: @hakre Thanks for the tip. I just had lots of free time with nothing else to do. So it was a welcome diversion and I went along. Interesting article. Never seen the particular persona explained before.